# `ack` doesn't show line numbers on a single file

Tags: ack

I'm using ack to search for a string. When I run it without a file argument, I get line numbers:

```
$> ack function
themes/README.txt
7:Drupal's sub-theme functionality to ensure easy maintenance and upgrades.

sites/default/default.services.yml
48:    # - The dump() function can be used in Twig templates to output information

...
```

But when I try to specify a file, I don't get line numbers.

```
$> ack function themes/README.txt
Drupal's sub-theme functionality to ensure easy maintenance and upgrades.
```

I've done some googling for a switch, but found no results. How do I get ack to show me line numbers on results from a single file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you don't provide any file, `ack` will search for all files in current directory and subdirectories. If a file contains matching pattern, `ack` print that filename, the line number and the line which matched pattern.

This behaviour does not apply for one file (See [ack documentation](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/), search for `-H` option).

Since when `ack` doesn't have `-n` option line `grep`, which will print line matched with its relative line number, you have two choices to work around this issue.

Forcing `ack` print filename with `-H`:

```
ack -H pattern file
```

or passing `/dev/null` as the second file:

```
ack pattern file /dev/null
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try with option `--with-filename`:

```
ack --with-filename 'function' themes/README.txt
```

This issue is raised as [bug](https://github.com/petdance/ack/issues/244) and issue has been moved [here](https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/196).

Answer (score 5):

There should be an option for this.  But if there isn't, you can trick `ack` into thinking there are two files to search through, by passing an extra `/dev/null` on the command line:

```bash
ack function themes/README.txt /dev/null
```

On a side note, the same trick can be used to make `grep(1)` show you a filename even when you're searching a single file:

```bash
grep function themes/README.txt /dev/null
```